# c# - new cmd process writing to existing allocated console

Tags: c#, multithreading, console-application

My project I am creating in C# makes use of multithreading, my Console Application solution uses +2 projects, 1 as a "main" project, then sub projects as the program's actual functions combined in 1 solution (with approriate references)

I know that for each process, only 1 console can be used, thus to my understanding, I should create a new cmd.exe process and assign this paticular thread's output to this console

problem: creating a simple process is easy with cmd.exe, it creates a new cmd console over the existing, thus 2 consoles. But reassigning the standard output,etc (ref code below). in the new sub thread program (aka not the main application), it starts to write in the existing console and not in the newly created console thus only 1 console visible,

I want the exising one visible aswel as the new console  with the appropriate output

am I missing something?

p.s. I am learning threading as well as this being a side project

```
        Process psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
        {
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
        };

        p = Process.Start(psi);

        Streamwriter sw = p.StandardInput;
        Streamreader sr = p.StandardOutput;
```

Comment: It looks like you're reusing `p`. Is anything happening to `p` outside this block of code?

Comment: you should try setting the redirects to false.

Comment: Also just as an FYI,  if you want to learn about .NET threading a good place to look is in the System.Threading namespace.  This will probably give you a better foothold than running separate processes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Vlad reusing?, no nothing else, this code block is in my subthread main(), afterwards i am calling a class which will perform the nessasary operations, thus 2 meathods in Program.Main() {processIOHandler- code above, and function class instance}

Comment: @kmacdonald does not work, throws exception of Standardln has not been redirected

Comment: apologies of my method(s) seems confusing, as this is my first threading project, I am testing out certain ideas, if you would like me to post code relelvant to the issue, just let me know

Comment: @kmacdonald I will defaintely visit that link, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just can't be done that way.

An instance of your program, even if is a console, is not a `cmd` window. It's a console.

Also, to work the way you want, you'll need to open the `StreamWriter` to the `StandardOutput` stream, since you want to *output* data... and that's not allowed by design.

The window is owned by its process, not its threads, so 1 process = 1 console window. If you want more console windows, use multiple processes and make them comunicate using interop.

Comment: thanks, i did not want to do it that way but seems like its the only option

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to using a thread to check for updates and redirecting the standard input/output as mentioned above